# I got an error while getting data from the API, how should I get the data if flutter?

Tags: flutter, api, dart

I am getting data from an `API` using a model. But I ran into a problem that when I get the `'gallery'` data, I get an error, that is, I get the data incorrectly. I need to get the `'gallery'` field and inside it take the `'url'` field - a link to the photo, in order to use it in the future. Can you tell me how to get the `'url'` field correctly?

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 35,
        "picture_url": null,
        "email_confirmed": false,
        "gallery": [
            {
                "url": "https://picture-staging.s3.eu-central.jpeg",
                "mime_type": "image/jpeg",
                "type": "gallery",
                "updated_at": "2022",
                "created_at": "2022"
            }
        ],
        "updated_at": "2022",
        "created_at": "2022"
    }
}
```

**model**

```
class User {
  final int id;
  List? gallery;

  User({
    required this.id,
    this.gallery,
  });

  User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : this(
          id: json['id'] as int,
          gallery: json['gallery']['url'],
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that is not your whole model, because that model is not accessing the `"data"` key on the json response, your model should start getting the key `data` then pass it to another class that in this case should be named `User`

here is a brief example

```dart
class User {
    User({
        required this.data,
    });

    final Data data;

    factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => User(
        data: Data.fromJson(json["data"]),
    );
}
```

The `Data` class could be like this:

```dart
class Data {
    Data({
        required this.id,
        required this.pictureUrl,
        required this.emailConfirmed,
        required this.gallery,
        required this.updatedAt,
        required this.createdAt,
    });

    final int id;
    final dynamic pictureUrl;
    final bool emailConfirmed;
    final List<Gallery> gallery;
    final String updatedAt;
    final String createdAt;

    factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Data(
        id: json["id"],
        pictureUrl: json["picture_url"],
        emailConfirmed: json["email_confirmed"],
        gallery: List<Gallery>.from(json["gallery"].map((x) => Gallery.fromJson(x))),
        updatedAt: json["updated_at"],
        createdAt: json["created_at"],
    );
    
}
```

I reccomend you using [Quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io/)

Comment: Ok, I'll try later and let you know.

Comment: And if Gallery comes empty null then it will give an error and there is no check here

Comment: If gallery can be null you should give it a default value, you can do this by changing the ` gallery: List<Gallery>.from(json["gallery"].map((x) => Gallery.fromJson(x)))` to `gallery: List<Gallery>.from(json["gallery"].map((x) => Gallery.fromJson(x) ?? []))` or giving default values on the Gallery class to the different fields

Answer (score 2):

In your API response, there is a list of gallery objects therefore you have to traverse through all of them.

```
User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    json = json['data'];
    id = json['id'];
    pictureUrl = json['picture_url'];
    emailConfirmed = json['email_confirmed'];
    if (json['gallery'] != null) {
      gallery = <Gallery>[];
      json['gallery'].forEach((v) {
        gallery!.add(new Gallery.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
  }
```

There are multiple tools that helps you create that .fromJson method, like [this](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/). Paste your json there and it will generate dart code for you, really helps me.

The usage should like this:

```
User user = User.fromJson(yourApiResponseJson);
print(user.id);
print(user.gallery); //prints entire list of gallery
print(user.gallery.first.url); //prints only first object url
```

Comment: Tell me, how can I then get the url field and display the image in ui ?

Comment: I will get the data, but how can I access it what to use in ui ?

Comment: I updated my reply with usage, please check it now. This is how you can access it.

Comment: I'll try later and let you know if it worked or not.

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can use [this](https://app.quicktype.io/) tool to generate your dart model from json.

Below is generated code from above tool

```
// final user = userFromJson(jsonString);
import 'dart:convert';

User userFromJson(String str) => User.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String userToJson(User data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class User {
  User({
    required this.data,
  });

  Data data;

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => User(
    data: Data.fromJson(json["data"]),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "data": data.toJson(),
  };
}

class Data {
  Data({
    this.id,
    this.pictureUrl,
    this.emailConfirmed,
    this.gallery,
    this.updatedAt,
    this.createdAt,
  });

  int? id;
  String? pictureUrl;
  bool? emailConfirmed;
  List<Gallery>? gallery;
  String? updatedAt;
  String? createdAt;

  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Data(
    id: json["id"],
    pictureUrl: json["picture_url"],
    emailConfirmed: json["email_confirmed"],
    gallery: List<Gallery>.from(json["gallery"].map((x) => Gallery.fromJson(x))),
    updatedAt: json["updated_at"],
    createdAt: json["created_at"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "picture_url": pictureUrl,
    "email_confirmed": emailConfirmed,
    "gallery": List<dynamic>.from(gallery.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    "updated_at": updatedAt,
    "created_at": createdAt,
  };
}

class Gallery {
  Gallery({
    this.url,
    this.mimeType,
    this.type,
    this.updatedAt,
    this.createdAt,
  });

  String? url;
  String? mimeType;
  String? type;
  String? updatedAt;
  String? createdAt;

  factory Gallery.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Gallery(
    url: json["url"],
    mimeType: json["mime_type"],
    type: json["type"],
    updatedAt: json["updated_at"],
    createdAt: json["created_at"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "url": url,
    "mime_type": mimeType,
    "type": type,
    "updated_at": updatedAt,
    "created_at": createdAt,
  };
}
```

// You can use like this

```
 final user = userFromJson(jsonString);
 String? url =  user.data?.gallery?.url;
```

Comment: Ok, I'll try later and let you know.